# What is the safest RAID Type for maintain the system?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

What is safest RAID Configuration to maintain the system without data loss? If you have `6 X 8TB` Disk On `RAID 10` it has `24TB` usage spaces and `1 disk failure` reserve and on `RAID 6` it has 2 Disk failure reserves.
What is best configuration for safety to maintain server withoud losses?

Answer (score 0):

If don't care about available disk space, you can create a single `RAID-1` volume with all your 6 drives if your RAID controller supports that. You can check [this post](https://superuser.com/q/489793/55645).

If you want to have more effective disk space with good protection or if your RAID controller does not support this number of drives as single `RAID-1` array, you can go with `RAID-6` array. `RAID-6` provides protection against two drives failure.

Comment: On Raid 1 have have 5 disk failure reserve? and on raid 6, how can i check how many disk are failed?

Comment: @VanGogh: Using `Raid-1`, you will have `number of disks -1`.  Disk status can be checked usually from server management console / BIOS / disk utility and/or whatever tools available.